# How can I split and map input like 'S1,10' to two variables one str and other integer

Tags: python, string, input, split, integer

I am reading an input 'S1,10'.  First component is a string and second is an integer.  They are separated by comma.

I have tried x = input().split(',').  This creates a list ['S1','10'].  How can I create a list ['S1', 10] where the second element is an integer?

I have solved this in a two step process.
bp = input().split(',')
bp[1] = int(bp[1])

Can it be done in a single step?  How can we split with different datatypes?

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language. Python?

Comment: I have solved this in a two step process.

Comment: _Why_ do you want a single step? It's not going to be any faster or more efficient if you do it in a "single step"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, if you really want to force it, it can be done in a single line

```py
x = [s if i == 0 else int(s) for i,s in enumerate(input().split(','))]
```

But at the end of the day, code is for humans to understand. If I were you I would keep what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. With this approach it is easy to vary which functions to apply to the parts of the split string.

```
x = [f(s) for f, s in zip([str, int], input().split(','))]
```